# $\operatorname{dim}V^G = \operatorname{dim}(V^\ast)^G$, or $G$ linearly reductive implies $V^G$ dual to $(V^\ast)^G$

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory, reductive-groups

**NOTE: The beginning part, which might sound like a lot of complicated theory to some, is just for completeness.  I might just need $\operatorname{dim}V^G = \operatorname{dim}(V^\ast)^G$, which anyone who knows what a representation is should understand.  It is also very likely that one can completely ignore the property "rational".**

In [Computational Invariant Theory](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642077968) by Harm Derksen and Gregor Kemper on page 39-40, theorem 2.2.5 states that if a linear algebraic group $G$ is linearly reductive, then for every rational representation $V$ of $G$ there exists a unique subrepresentation $W$ of $V$ such that $V = V^G \oplus W$ (i.e. $W$ is the unique module complement of $V^G$).  This is the main statement I would like to understand.

A linear algebraic group $G$ is called linearly reductive if and only if for every rational representation $V$ we have the following: For all $v \in V^G \setminus \{0\}$ there exists a linear invariant $\varphi \in (V^\ast)^G$ such that $\varphi (v) \neq 0$. (See [Computational Invariant Theory](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642077968), p.38, definition 2.2.1)

In other words, $G$ is linearly reductive if and only if for every rational representation $V$ of $G$, $\left. b \right|_{(V^\ast)^G \times V^G}$ is non-degenerate in the right variable, where $b \colon V^\ast \times V \rightarrow K$, $(\varphi,v) \mapsto \varphi(v)$ is the canonical pairing.

To show the statement, the book claims that for a linearly reductive group $G$ and a rational representation $V$, we have that $V^G$ and $(V^\ast)^G$ are dual to each other, which is equivalent to saying that $\left. b \right|_{(V^\ast)^G \times V^G}$ is non-degenerate in both variables.  This is what I cannot show and what I am having difficulties with.

We have non-degeneracy in the right variable by definition of "linearly reductive", so it suffices (it is in fact equivalent) to show that $\operatorname{dim}V^G = \operatorname{dim}(V^\ast)^G$.  Again, I just can't prove this, I always fail.

Notes:

- I am pretty sure that "rational" isn't needed, the statement should also be true if we replace " rational representation" by "representation", and replace "linear algebraic group" by "group".
- I believe that $\operatorname{dim}V^G = \operatorname{dim}(V^\ast)^G$ is true for any representation, even if $G$ isn't linearly reductive, but I am not sure.  In any case, if we can show this, it would be all I need in order to show everything I need.

Some other definitions that some might not know or have forgotten:

- If $G$ acts on $V$, then $G $acts on $V^\ast$ via $\sigma.\varphi(v) := \varphi(\sigma^{-1}.v)$, where $\sigma \in G$, $\varphi \in V^\ast$, $v \in V$.  $V^\ast$ is a representation of $G$ via this definition.
- If $V$ is a representation of a group $G$, then $V^G := \{\, v \in V \mid \forall \sigma \in G : \sigma.v = v \,\}$ is the space of all invariants.  This is a subrepresentation of $V$.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

**EDITS:**

- "representation" here means "finite representation"

Comment: Actually, the statement is false even for rational representations. Presumably they want the representation to be finite dimensional, as otherwise one could have the group act trivially on a space with countable dimension and get much larger dual. To show they have the same dimension in this case, take a basis for the fixed points in one, extend to a basis for the full space and note that the duals of the basis of fixed points will be fixed points in the dual.

Comment: By the way, it is also common to actually define linearly reductive by the property that all finite dimensional representations are completely reducible, which avoids a lot of this complication.

Comment: Ah yes, maybe I should have specified: representations are here always assumed to be finite dimensional.

Comment: Also: I prove that these are all equivalent.  No matter how I define it, I need to show the statement I wrote about, since I need many characterizations, including this definition I gave, for my work.  I need to prove the equivalences of each characterizations (id est that they are in fact characterizations). 

I have tried your idea, but it doesn't work since we don't yet have module complements (which is what I want to show).  Two different supervisors and my professor of mine have noted that your idea doesn't bring us much further.  It seems like it works, but it doesn't.

Comment: You are right, I was using the stronger property you are trying to prove without noticing. Fortunately, there is now a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $V$ is finite dimensional, the canonical map $V \to (V^*)^*$ is an isomorphism of $G$-representations. Consider the map
$$V \cong (V^*)^* \to ((V^*)^G)^* \quad \text{given by restriction} \quad v \mapsto v|_{(V^*)^G}.$$ This map is surjective with kernel $K$ equal to the space of all $v \in V$ such that $\phi(v)=0$ for all $\phi \in (V^*)^G$. The group $G$ acts trivially on the target $((V^*)^G)^*$ of this map, and if $U \subseteq V$ is a subspace such that $G$ acts trivially on $V/U$, then each linear functional on $V/U$ defines an element of $(V^*)^G$. It follows that $K \subseteq U$, and hence $((V^*)^G)^*$ is the largest quotient of $V$ on which $G$ acts trivially.

This quotient is usually called the space of *co-invariants* of $V$, and is typically denoted $V_G$. By construction it is dual to the space $(V^*)^G$ you are interested in, and replacing $V$ by $V^*$ we see that $(V^*)_G$ is dual to $V^G$. On the other hand, there is a natural (functorial in $V$) map $V^G \to V_G$ obtained by composing the inclusion $V^G \subseteq V$ with the projection $V \to ((V^*)^G)^*=V_G$.

The condition that for each $v \in V^G \setminus \{0 \}$ there is some $\phi \in (V^*)^G$ with $\phi(v) \neq 0$ implies that the intersection of $K$ with $V^G$ is $0$, or in other words that the canonical map $V^G \to V_G$ is injective for all representations $V$. Applying this to $V^*$ shows that the canonical map $(V^*)^G \to (V^*)_G$ is injective as well. Thus
$$\mathrm{dim}(V_G)=\mathrm{dim}(V^*)^G \leq \mathrm{dim}(V^*)_G=\mathrm{dim}(V^G).$$ Hence the map $V^G \to V_G=((V^*)^G)^*$ is an isomorphism for all representations, so $V^G$ and $(V^*)^G$ are dual to one another as claimed.

To see that the reductive condition is actually necessary, you should look at the prototypical non-reductive groups: groups of upper triangular unipotent matrices. So let $k$ be a field and consider the group $U$ of linear transformations of $V=k^3$ consisting of all matrices $u$ of the form
$$u=\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & a & b \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right).$$ One checks that $V^U$ is the span of the first basis vector, hence of dimension $1$, and also that the quotient by it is the space $V_U$ of co-invariants, which is therefore of dimension $2$.

Comment: Very very nice.  Thank you so much.  I can't believe the book doesn't provide me with a proof.  This is not something a normal reader would come up with by themselves, I think...

Comment: @Bert You’re welcome! I haven’t read the book, so I’m not sure what the intended audience is, or whether or not its fair to expect the reader to believe the claim you asked about at the point it was made!